# Langchain prints Context before question and answer

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

```
import os
import nltk
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
from langchain.llms import GPT4All
from langchain.callbacks.base import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader, PyPDFLoader, DirectoryLoader, TextLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
from transformers import pipeline
import faiss



# Define the paths
gpt4all_path = './models/gpt4all-converted.bin'

# Create the callback manager
callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])

# Create the embeddings and llm objects
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
llm = GPT4All(model=gpt4all_path, callback_manager=callback_manager, verbose=True)

# Load the local index
index = FAISS.load_local("my_faiss_index", embeddings)

# Initialize the question-answering model
qa_model = pipeline("question-answering", model="distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad", tokenizer="distilbert-base-cased")


# Define the prompt template
template = """
Context: {context}
Question: {question}
Answer: {answer}
"""""

# Define the similarity search function
def similarity_search(query, index, k=3):
    try:
        matched_docs = index.similarity_search(query, k=k)
        return matched_docs
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred during similarity search: ", e)
        return []

# Split the documents into sentences
def split_into_sentences(document):
    return nltk.sent_tokenize(document)

# Select the best sentences based on the question
def select_best_sentences(question, sentences):
    results = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        answer = qa_model(question=question, context=sentence)
        if answer['score'] > 0.8:  # You can tune this threshold based on your requirements
            results.append(sentence)
    return results


def answer_question(question):
    # Get the most similar documents
    matched_docs = similarity_search(question, index)

    # Convert the matched documents into a list of sentences
    sentences = []
    for doc in matched_docs:
        sentences.extend(split_into_sentences(doc.page_content))

    # Select the best sentences
    best_sentences = select_best_sentences(question, sentences)

    context = "\n".join([doc.page_content for doc in matched_docs])
    question = question

    # Create the prompt template
    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["context","question", "answer"])

    # Initialize the LLMChain
    llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt_template, llm=llm)

    # Generate the answer
    generated_text = llm_chain.run(context=context, question=question, answer='', max_tokens=512, temperature=0.0, top_p=0.05)
    
    # Extract only the answer from the generated text
    answer_start_index = generated_text.find("Answer: ") + len("Answer: ")
    answer = generated_text[answer_start_index:]

    return answer


# Main loop for continuous question-answering
while True:
    # Get the user's question
    question = input("Chatbot: ")


    # Check if the user wants to exit
    if question.lower() == "exit":
        break

    # Generate the answer
    answer = answer_question(question)

    # Print the answer
    print("Answer:", answer)
```

Been struggling a bit to have the context not printed before the question and answer. I have tried many things to do this but either the context is then not used by the LLM or it will print the context no matter what. The printing of context also makes this very very slow, as sometimes it will keep printing context for 15-20 seconds.Any ideas?